# $.post() receive variable back from php

Tags: php, jquery

I send from javascript 2 values to a php.

```
function sendValue(str,str2){
        $.post("/phpfolder/updaterate.php",{ sendValue: str, sendValue2 : str2 },
            function(data){
            $('#display').html(data.returnValue);
            }, "json");
        }
```

My php file executes ....

and I want to send back a variable $x

```
<?php
...    
echo json_encode($x);
?>
```

where and what i`m missing?
I searched for examples, but nothing...

Comment: What does $x contain? Whad does firebug console show? You should probably read this: http://ajaxian.com/archives/ajax-debugging-with-firebug

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery, reading JSON variables received from PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455991/jquery-reading-json-variables-received-from-php)

Comment: Why data.returnValue ?

Comment: What are you expecting? What is happening? Everyone here is now just guessing stuff... which they seem to be eager to do...

Comment: try data instead of data.returnValue

Comment: There are hundreds of examples on this website itself, guess you should search a little better ; ))

Comment: $x contains some html spans and inputs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_encode` can take an array as parameter.

You want to display `data.returnValue`. So construct an array like this:

```
...
echo json_encode( array('returnValue' => $x) );
exit()
```

Comment: So you know what `$x` is then? -1

Comment: From OP's comment above, it is a string.

Comment: thks, i was confused function(data){
            $('#display').html(data.returnValue); i understood now

Comment: OK. I suggest you read up on how to use $.ajax (and other jQuery Ajax functions), how to construct and parse JSON objects and how to use the firebug/webkit console to debug ajax/http requests.

Answer (score 1):

Try to test these things

```
function sendValue(str,str2){
        $.post("/phpfolder/updaterate.php",{ 'sendValue': str, 'sendValue2' : str2 },//add '  to the name of the variables
            function(data){
            alert('inside the function');//test if is getting inside the function
            $('#display').html(data.returnValue);
            }, "json");
        }
```

In the php you have to return an array.

```
<?php
$x['returnValue'] = 'whatever';//The key of the array has to be the name used in the function(data)
echo json_encode($x);
?>
```